# zip archive quirk php

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to see if a directory exists inside a ziparchive using `statName` and I have come across an odd quirk.

When I generate a zip file in php I add the files in this fashion: `$this->zip->addFile($file, $path);` where `$file` is `C:\xampp\htdocs\images\uploads\about.png` and `$path` is the internal path `images/uploads/about.png`. If I try and see if `images/uploads/` exists when checking the zip in another routine using `statName` I get a false response even though the files and directories exist if opened by winzip.

For testing I made a new zip using winzip, and added a folder `images` and in and then `uploads` mimicking the above and checked if `images/uploads/` existed using `statName` and it does!

I've made an output of the zip file using a loop and you can clearly see in the ziparchive created zip folder there is no verbatim `images/uploads/` directory, yet there are files in those directories if you open the zip and as seen in output. Whereas the winzip one has the directory listed verbatim.

[image]

What is preventing the `statName` from showing up with the ZipArchive created zip file? I can only assume its because the dir is not listed verbatim, but that doesn't make any sense as those directories do exist! Is there something I don't know in the way ZipArchive handles adding files?

Comment: Can you `statName` any of those other files in that directory successfully?   I think the issue is because despite being a directory `images/uploads/` isn't an entry _per se_ - the full paths are. Try creating a blank directory (ZipArchive fashion, not Winzip) and then `statName` against the empty directory and see what you get.

Comment: @Crackertastic i'll tell you what works: if i make a zip file, then add a folder using the `addEmptyDir` I can see if that folder exists using `statName`. Hence my guess, that `addFile` with paths does some quirky stuff. And to answer your question, I can indeed see if a file exists using statName in `image/uploads/about.png`